# Short-term contract (3 months) opportunity

Tags: interviewing, job-search, contracts

I'm currently on a job hunt and got contacted by a recruiter and asked if I'd like to consider an opportunity to work with one of the biggest companies in our country. However, it's only a 3-month contract (I know it's really short!). I'm not really looking for a short-term contract, however as I want to grab this opportunity because I'm still looking into the possibility that I might have a permanent job with them in the future - given that this is a great opportunity for me to begin with.

A **little background** on my work experience: my last position was on **Client Servicing** side in an agency and this 3-month contract will be a **Brand Consultant** which will be now on a client side.

**Question:**

- If they start asking *"why are you considering this temporary job though you're resume shows you never had temporary job before*" or *"what are you going to do after your contract expires?"* what should I tell them? I don't want to show that I'm just here for the sake of having a job, but I just want to take the risk that I might get a permanent job with them in the future and build my career with them + the position is a good start for me.
- If I got accepted in this short-term contract, ended it and got no renewal nor permanent position, will it look like I'm job-hopping if I listed this on my resume?

P.S.:
I've read [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/54376/how-should-i-behave-with-a-temporary-contract/54382#54382) already however we have different situations as I'm not intentionally seeking for temporary positions as of the moment nor waiting any job offer in the next few months.

Comment: There are some companies which have explicit rules about not hiring temps /contractors immediately as full-time. If this is what you hope to do, you should ask ***them***  whether it is likely to help or hurt your longer term goals (or have no effect).

Comment: Final unclear vote cast. Your current situation and plans are relevant details that you've left out. Are you currently employed? If so, why would you leave for a 3-month position? What are your plans for the situation where the contract ends and you're left unemployed? You don't seem to be thinking this through. For most of such contracts it is *vastly* unlikely that they'll be extended or that they'll hire you full-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's contracting, which is a completely different ballgame from permanent employment. It's normal for contractors to have a long sequence of short contracts strung together. It's not "job-hopping", it's contracting. The company wants you because you can fill a short term gap, and when the contract is over, you are gone. No job security, no integration into the company, but a daily rate that compensates for it - my rule of thumb is that 150 daily rates should equal the annual pre-tax salary.

Why are you taking this three month job (if they ask you)? Because you want to try out if contracting is the way for you to go. They don't expect dedication to the company or loyalty to the company (beyond the dedication and loyalty they can expect because they pay you). They expect you to be gone in three months. "I see this as an opportunity to maybe get a permanent job" is *not* a positive.

If they ask you "what are you going to do after the contract expires" - that would be absolutely weird. They are not interested, and it's none of their business. They are not going to ask that question. If they ask, which they won't, the answer is "I hope to have the next contract signed at that point in time".

Comment: Would it be a way for the company to "test" the applicant's skills and personality, and if he was good they will directly hire him later?

Comment: No, you would hire an employee with a three month probation period. When you advertise for contracting jobs, you will get contractors applying who want to leave and go to the next contracting job.